# Is the dual of a complete topological vector space always complete?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis

Let $X$ be a complete topological vector space (over $\mathbb{C}$ say), and $X'$ its dual with the weak*-topology. Then is $X'$ always complete? You may assume $X$ is locally convex if you like.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the weak* topology, the dual is a (topological) subspace of

$$\mathbb{C}^X = \prod_{x\in X} \mathbb{C}.$$

A product of complete spaces is always complete, so $\mathbb{C}^X$ is complete ($\mathbb{C}$ is complete), and thus $X'$ is complete in the weak* topology if and only if it is a closed subspace of $\mathbb{C}^X$. The algebraic dual $X^\ast$ (the space of all linear functionals, continuous or not) is a closed subspace of $\mathbb{C}^X$, hence complete.

If the topological and the algebraic dual coincide, $X'$ is hence complete in the weak* topology.

If $X$ is locally convex, then $X'$ is dense in $X^\ast$ in the topology of pointwise convergence, hence in that case $X'$ is complete if and only if $X' = X^\ast$.

To see that $X'$ is dense in $X^\ast$ for locally convex $X$, take any linear functional $\lambda\colon X\to\mathbb{C}$. A neighbourhood of $\lambda$ contains a set of the form

$$V(\lambda;\varepsilon,x_1,\dotsc,x_n) = \left\{ \mu \in X^\ast : \lvert \mu(x_i) - \lambda(x_i)\rvert < \varepsilon, 1 \leqslant i \leqslant n \right\}$$

for some $\varepsilon > 0$ and finitely many $x_i \in X$. We need to see that any such set contains a continuous functional. But $Y = \operatorname{span} \{x_1,\,\dotsc,\,x_n\}$ is finite-dimensional, hence $\lambda\lvert_Y$ is continuous. By Hahn-Banach, there is a $\varphi \in X'$ with $\varphi\lvert_Y = \lambda\lvert_Y$, and thus

$$\varphi \in V(\lambda;\varepsilon,x_1,\dotsc,x_n) \cap X',$$

even for all $\varepsilon > 0$, where only the $x_i$ are kept fixed.

Comment: So the topology you give $\mathbb{C}^X$ is pointwise convergence? If I assume the topology of $X$ is induced by (countably many) seminorms, then is $X'$ complete?

Comment: The product topology is the topology of pointwise convergence. If the topology of $X$ is induced by countably many seminorms (including by a single norm), and $X$ is infinite-dimensional, then $X'$ is never complete in the weak* topology if $X$ is complete.

Comment: Oh, you mean the product topology on the product space. But I don't agree with one of your claims, just think about the Schwartz class, the space of rapidly decreasing functions, its topology is induced by countably many norms, and its dual, the space of tempered distributions, is complete yet.

Comment: The last wasn't right, or at least I can't prove it, it may be possible that a topology finer than $\sigma(X,X^\ast)$ can be defined by countably many seminorms. But the space of tempered distributions is complete _in its strong topology_, not in its weak topology (which coincides with its weak* topology since the space is reflexive).

Comment: What is $\sigma (X,X^*)$? Also, just now I found an exercise in a functional analysis book says that if the topology of $X$ is induced by (countably many) seminorms, then $X′$ is complete (even true when $X$ is not complete). Anyway, thank you!

Comment: When you have a dual system $E,F$, then $\sigma(E,F)$ is the topology on $E$ that is induced by the seminorms $p_f \colon e \mapsto \lvert f(e)\rvert$ for $f\in F$, it's the topology of pointwise convergence on $F$,identifying $E$ with a subspace of $F^\ast$. Regarding the exercise, that is about the completeness of $X'$ in the strong topology, not in the weak* topology. The dual of a normed space is a Banach space in its strong topology, but in its weak* topology, it is only complete when the space is finite-dimensional.